# How to declare async function as a variable in flutter(dart)?

Tags: flutter, dart

In flutter, we can declare a function as variable and call it like this

```
MyWidget((){print('HI');});

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget{
  final Function sayHi;

  MyWidget(this.sayHi);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    sayHi();
    return ...
  }
}
```

But what if `sayHi()` is a async function? How to declare a async function as variable? There seems no class like `AsyncFunction`. So how to achive that?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Async functions are normal functions with some sugar on top. Here, the function variable type just needs to specify that it returns a Future:

```
class Example {
  Future<void> Function() asyncFuncVar;
  Future<void> asyncFunc() async => print('Do async stuff...');

  Example() {
    asyncFuncVar = asyncFunc;
    asyncFuncVar().then((_) => print('Hello'));
  }
}

void main() => Example();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Awesome, glad that works for you. Could you select an answer so this questions gets archived as answered? Thanks!

Comment: Thank u very much :) or you can do; final Function xx; and when using; await(xx() as Future<void>);

Comment: I couldn't find an explanation on this syntax ANYWHERE on the internet. I just wanted to ask for confirmation, Future<void> is what the object of class Function returns, and Function() <- these parentheses contain the arguments for the Function, is that correct?

Comment: @Cedric Yes, that is correct. Think of it as declaring a function without a body, replacing the function name with "Function", and appending a variable name. The Function type can specify the typical type params (generics), params,  named params, optional params. See the [spec](https://dart.dev/guides/language/specifications/DartLangSpec-v2.10.pdf) section *9.3 Type of a Function* for more info.

Comment: I was about to open a new question, It did help, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  void asyncFunc() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5));
    print('printed after 5 seconds');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(asyncFunc),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final void Function() asyncFunc;

  const MyWidget(this.asyncFunc);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialButton(
      onPressed: asyncFunc,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. What I want to do is to use the .then() when calling the function. But `asyncFunc` in `MyWidget` is not recognized as a async function so I can't use `asyncFunc().then(...)`. Is that possible? Thanks again.

Comment: oh.. declare the method as Future